# How to set terminal title on taskbar(panel)?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I can set the title of terminal using "set Title", but that title is not visible when the terminal is minimalized. the default title is being shown on the taskbar(where all open applications are visible). How to change that title?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using Unity and you want to change the mouse over title of the terminal icon - [showed on this screenshot](http://imgur.com/fbeHx). Correct?

Comment: @jnv i'm not using that. I have normal taskbar like in windows and console's icon is placed there. I would like that every console have a specific title (i have a lot of them)

Comment: @101 It would be helpful if you mentioned which version of Ubuntu you were running and what login session you are using (it sounds at the moment like you're using Ubuntu Classic, which is GNOME 2).

Answer (score 2):

In the profile's settings (*Edit > Profile preferences*), on tab *Title and Command*, set the default title and make sure to select *Keep initial title* in the combobox:
[image: Terminal Profile title].

For multiple titles, use Gnome Terminal's `-t` or `--title=` switch. For each title, create a launcher or a shell script which will execute something like `gnome-terminal -t "My awesome title here"`. Other option would be to create a separate profile for each title and execute terminal with e.g. `--window-with-profile=PROFILENAME` option - see `man gnome-terminal`.

If this won't work, I'll need more info on your configuration, especially what version of Ubuntu and what desktop environment/session (e.g. Gnome Classic) you use - screenshot showing the non-changed title in taskbar would be handy too.