# Set the terminal title in a .desktop started application

Tags: .desktop, xdg-open

I've an application that I want to start via an entry in the upper gnome panel using a .desktop file, it has to run inside a terminal.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Icon[en_US]=/home/USER/bin/APPDIR/logo.png
Name[en_US]=APPLICATIONNAME
Exec=REALAPPLICATIONCOMMANDLINE
Path=APPLICATIONDIR
Comment[en_US]=COMMENT
Name=APPLICATIONNAME
Comment=COMMENT
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

That part works fine.

But the terminal is still titled 'Terminal', and to differentiate it from the other terminals I have running I'd like to change the terminal's title.

I've found [one way](https://askubuntu.com/q/40032/84169) to do it, but it requires that you run the terminal command, thus

```
Exec=gnome-terminal --title APPNAME ...ArgsToRunRealApplication...
```

instead of the actual command you want to run.

I'm hoping that there's either a parameter, or another Key=Value pair that I just haven't found yet, to set the title, *without* using gnome-terminal directly to run the command.

I suppose I could write a script that would set the title, then run the application, but that's only a little better than using gnome-terminal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Leave the Exec untouched and add those two lines on top of the script invoked by the XTERM:

```
test -x /usr/bin/xtitle || sudo apt-get install -y xtitle || exit 1
xtitle "My Title"
```

Comment: The Exec is not a script currently.  I was hoping to avoid that.  See last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I neither know any solution that doesn't require a script. The following line in a script should work without installing anything new:

```
printf '\033]2;My Title\a'
```

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/358985 for explanation.